# MySQL View Select N days in the future

Tags: mysql, select, view

I have a mySQL view that I would like to be able to find all the records with expirationDate that is EXACTLY N amount of days from now.  For example, I want to find all the records with an expirationDate that is EXACTLY 90 days from now so I can email the person to let them know their course is expiring. Both dateCompleted and expirationDate are of the datetime type.

Structure:

```
id  can firstName   lastName    email   course  curriculum  group   stageNum    stage   dateCompleted   expirationDate
```

Data Example:

```
1   123456789   John    Smith   jsmith@gmail.edu    PHS Conflict of Interest    Conflict of Interest mini-course    Conflict of Interest    1   Stage 1 2012-12-07 02:52:24 2015-12-07 02:52:24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you results with `expirationDate` 90 days from now:

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE DATE(expirationDate) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using some of the [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like `DATE_ADD`:

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE expirationDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY);
```

Comment: I need only the records that are EXACTLY 90 days in the future.  This shows all the records that are from now to 90 days in the future.

Comment: You can always adjust that to be `expirationDate=DATE_ADD(...)` if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM courses 
WHERE DATE(DATE_ADD(expirationDate, INTERVAL -90 DAY)) = CURRENT_DATE
```